# Wrongly accepted stalemate but game is a clear win?

Tags: rules, stalemate

What will happen when we wrongly accepted stalemate and thereafter 02-03 seconds we noticed it was not a stalemate but a clear win?

Answer (score 6):

According to the [FIDE Laws of Chess](http://aekphotography.co.uk/CAA/Laws2018.pdf):

> 5.2.3  The game is drawn upon agreement between the two players during the game, provided both players have made at least one move. This immediately ends the game.

However, the annotations to rule 5.1.1 state:

> Particularly in junior tournaments it can be discovered that one player accepts he was mated to discover later that he could prevent the mate.  If a result is reported by both players that can be accepted.  Where a player announces mate and immediately shakes hands only for it to be discovered seconds later that the move played was not mate he should not be given the win despite any handshake.

I would tend to think that a false stalemate should be handled like a false checkmate, and the game should be resumed if the error was discovered within seconds.

Comment: Especially if they "noticed it was a clear win" was because they noticed it was actually checkmate, not stalemate. Checkmate ends the game and whatever happens after doesn't influence the result.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I wouldn't quite say that "whatever" happens after doesn't affect the result; after all, "If a result is reported by both players that can be accepted."

Comment: But that is the opposite case, where there was neither checkmate nor stalemate. The rule that those end the game immediately doesn't apply.